# Call delegate function later C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on 4.5 library and I want to call function pass as parameter in specific place of my method.

Currently the method passed as parameter is called before the one where I pass the parameter.

Here is my currently code

```
ApiCall<EntityMessage>.CallApi(token, ServicesMessage.Get(messageId));

public static HttpResponseMessage CallApi(string token, T method)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = ServicesAPIAuth.CheckToken(token);

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        //want to call the method passed here
        response = ServicesJsonWebApi.FormatJsonApiResponse(method, HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    return response;
}
```

So I want to call `ServicesMessage.Get(messageId)` where I wrote the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually looking for is a `Func<T>` delegate

```
public static HttpResponseMessage CallApi(string token, Func<T> method) {
    HttpResponseMessage response = ServicesAPIAuth.CheckToken(token);

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        //call the method passed here
        response = ServicesJsonWebApi.FormatJsonApiResponse(method(), HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    return response;
}
```

And then call it like

```
ApiCall<EntityMessage>.CallApi(token, () => ServicesMessage.Get(messageId));
```